# Test if a key-value pair exists in nested object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I wrote a function to check if a nested object contains the key-value pair matched as parameter as following.

```
eq:
const obj ={
   "a":{
      "b":{
         "c1":["1","2"],
         "c2":"3"
      },
      "b2":"values",
      "b3": {"c5": "v"},
   },
   "a2":["v1","v2"],
   "a3":"v1"
}
checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "a3", "v1") // true
checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "a3", "v2") // false
checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "a2", ["v1","v2"]) // true
checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "a3", "v1") // true
checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "b3", {"c5": "v"}) // true
```

```
function checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(
  obj: Record<string, any>,
  objKey: string,
  objValue: string | Array<string>
): boolean {

  if (typeof obj !== 'object') return false;
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(objKey)) {

    return JSON.stringify(obj[objKey]) === JSON.stringify(objValue)
  }
  for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
    if (checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(value, objKey, objValue)) return true
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: updated. code totally works

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of the function, I would expect this test to return `true`, but your implementation returns `false`.  So, either your description is unclear, or your implementation is buggy.

```
const obj ={
   "a":{
      "b":{
         "a3":"v2",
         "c1":["1","2"],
         "c2":"3"
      },
      "b2":"values",
      "b3": {"c5": "v"},
   },
   "a2":["v1","v2"],
   "a3":"v1"
}
checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "a3", "v2") // false, but I would expect true
```

Comment: we have "a3": "v1" as first level that is why it return false. not sure how i can handle that

Answer (score 0):

### Main review

Your code works well in most cases, but the biggest change I recommend in order to skip over false positives would be to change the following lines

```
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(objKey)) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj[objKey]) === JSON.stringify(objValue)
  }
```

to the following (move `JSON.stringify(obj[objKey]) === JSON.stringify(objValue)` into the conditional statement and return true):

```
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(objKey) && JSON.stringify(obj[objKey]) === JSON.stringify(objValue)) {
    return true;
  }
```

As [200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) pointed out, your code returns false when a key exists in one part of the whole object but doesn't match and another key exists elsewhere which does match. This change will check whether a key matches first and proceeds to perform the recursive search for another key with matching value.

In the following code snippet, I changed the code to JavaScript so it could be run here in this post.

```js
function checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, objKey, objValue) {
  if (typeof obj !== "object") return false;
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(objKey) && JSON.stringify(obj[objKey]) === JSON.stringify(objValue)) {
    return true;
  }
  for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
    if (checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(value, objKey, objValue))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      a3: "v2",
      c1: ["1", "2"],
      c2: "3"
    },
    b2: "values",
    b3: {
      c5: "v"
    },
  },
  a2: ["v1", "v2"],
  a3: "v1"
};
console.log(checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "a3", "v1"));
console.log(checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "a3", "v2"));
console.log(checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "a2", ["v1", "v2"]));
console.log(checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "b3", {
  c5: "v"
}));
// Added a check that should return false
console.log(checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "b2", "novalue"));
```

If the pattern of object properties is:

- first level property name `/^a\d*$/`
- second level property name `/^b\d*$/`
- third level property name `/^c\d*$/`
- etc.

Then this *may* not be necessary.

### Other thoughts

When I first ran your code, I received an error: `Argument of type '{ c5: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[]'.` which referenced the following line:

```js
checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(obj, "b3", { c5: "v" })
```

I resolved this by adding  `| object` to the `objValue` parameter as follows:

```
function checkNestedObjectByKeyValue(
  obj: Record<string, any>,
  objKey: string,
  objValue: string | Array<string> | object
): boolean {
```